# Is it possible to delete a cookies using its VALUE NOT NAME using JavaScript? If yes, then how?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

```
function addit(x, y, z) {
    c = document.getElementById("count");
    iname = document.getElementById("itemname");
    pic = document.getElementById(z).src;
    n = parseInt(c.value);
    n += 1;
    document.cookie = "itemname" + n + "=" + x;
    document.cookie = "itemprice" + n + "=" + y;
    document.cookie = "itemimgsrc" + n + "=" + pic;
    c.value = n;
}
```

I am creating cookies with the above function successfully and now need a function to delete these cookies but NOT with the NAME of the cookies but using their VALUE. The one who have down voted my question, read the question again please, everywhere people have explained to delete a cookie using its NAME but I need to do it using its VALUE, NOT NAME, Thanks.

Comment: No its not the duplicate of what you have posted. At least read the question and details before down voting.

Comment: What's wrong with this question?

Comment: how is this a duplicate anyways? and why does that claim keep getting upvotes while the op keeps getting downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
document.cookie = "itemname" + n + "=''";
```

Or like this:

```
document.cookie = "itemname" + n + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;";
```

Just give it no value and a previous date

Comment: I cannot us the cookie name, I need to do it using its value. I know how to do it with the cookie name.

Comment: suppose there is a cookie itenname1=firstitem then I want to delete this cookies using the value firsitem not with the name of the cookie i.e itenname1.

Comment: The only way you can delete a cookie is by name AFAIK, therefore you'd have to run through all the cookies you've set and look for one which has value `firstitem`, get it's name, then delete it

Comment: I know what to do but doesn't know how to do that's why I have asked.